# How to confirm receipt of Bitcoin using Electrum?

Tags: electrum

After providing my public address to receive bitcoin, how are transactions tracked or audited?

I'd like to view on the blockchain the status of receipt of bitcoin to the address with the understanding that it can take time to percolate and finalize.

Answer (score 2):

You can check number of confirmations in Electrum or use one of the below methods to check confirmations for you transaction:

1. Check multiple explorers for transaction. Examples: [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/) and [blockstream.info](https://blockstream.info/)
2. Setup one of the open source block explorers and do not rely on other services. Example: [NBXplorer](https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer)
3. You can setup and use your own Electrum server this also improves privacy while using Electrum: https://github.com/romanz/electrs
4. Connect your Bitcoin full node with Electrum using this plugin if using a watch-only wallet: https://github.com/bwt-dev/bwt-electrum-plugin

6 confirmations can be considered safe and final for most of the Bitcoin transactions.